Trouble with how to constraint a lifetime on a trait method
I am trying to implement nom's InputIter trait on my custom input type for dealing with tokens instead of string. My input type is implemented as follows:
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct TokenInput<'a> {
    pub tokens: Vec<SpannedToken<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> TokenInput<'a> {
    pub fn from_lexer(lexer: Lexer<'a, Token>) -> Self {
        Self {
            tokens: TokenLexerIterator::from(lexer).collect(),
        }
    }

    pub fn iter(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a SpannedToken<'a>> {
        self.tokens.iter()
    }
}

Where SpannedToken<'a> is just a struct containing my token as lexed by the logos library alongside the span and a string slice to the input it references (hence the lifetime).
Now I'm stuck on implementing the InputIter trait. I now have this:
impl<'a> InputIter for TokenInput<'a> {
    type Item = &'a SpannedToken<'a>;
    type IterElem = std::slice::Iter<'a, SpannedToken<'a>>;
    type Iter = Enumerate<Self::IterElem>;

    fn iter_indices(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        todo!()
    }

    fn iter_elements(&self) -> Self::IterElem {
        self.iter()
    }

    fn position<P>(&self, predicate: P) -> Option<usize>
    where
        P: Fn(Self::Item) -> bool,
    {
        todo!()
    }

    fn slice_index(&self, count: usize) -> Result<usize, nom::Needed> {
        todo!()
    }
}

However, the body of iter_elements gives me the following:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/token.rs:210:9
    |
200 | impl<'a> InputIter for TokenInput<'a> {
    |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
209 |     fn iter_elements(&self) -> Self::IterElem {
    |                      - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
210 |         self.iter()
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`

So I have to somehow constraint &self to outlive the iterator, but can't for the life of me figure it out. Simplest is to just do fn iter_elements(&'a self) -> Self::IterElem like in the impl block of TokenInput<'a>, but that changes the function signature, which would not implement the trait.
Question is, how can I constraint &self to live long enough without changing the method signature? Or if there's an other solution please do give a suggestion.

You're out of luck, the design of the trait means that Iter and IterElem cannot borrow from self.

That's a bummer. Looking at the implementation of this trait for &str, it seems that Item = char, so translating it to my case it would mean I'd have to iterate over SpannedToken<'a>, cloning my struct?
